# Click button using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am new to python selenium. I want to click the Iniciar session(Login button)[image] on this web site. I have tried using the XPath, CSS selector, CSS Path, and class name.

I use the below code to click the button:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/pralo/Downloads/DE/chromedriver", chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://www.panamacompra.gob.pa/Inicio/#/')
sleep(10)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[text()=" Iniciar sesión"]').click()
```

I get the below error for the above code execution:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (389, 1470)

Can anyone help me understand the reason for this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize the [`driver.execute_script()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) method:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.panamacompra.gob.pa/Inicio/#/')
sleep(10)
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn-blue-dark')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

The `driver.execute_script()` method allows you to run JavaScript code in your Python program!